# update git version in docker container

Tags: node.js, git, docker

I am implementing a node.js application in docker, that needs to make use of the git worktree feature. However, even if I do :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git=2.10.0
```

it can't find any other version after 2.1.0

I am building the image from :

```
FROM node:4.4.2
```

How can I get the latest git version that supports the worktree feature installed on a docker container

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of this post, no [package repos from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=git) include a version beyond 2.9. If you need a newer version, you'll need to download and install that from [source](https://github.com/git/git) which is [documented on git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git), or find another repo.

Answer (score 0):

From some other answers (credit to @Alex Karshin), this solution works for me in the Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git
```

Answer (score -2):

See https://askubuntu.com/a/568596/159234

```
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa && apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

Comment: the node images are debian based

Comment: Also confirmed that this does not work if you are using the official Node Docker images as they run Debian. The PPA is only for Ubuntu.